# How to use valid token in iframe from current web application?

Tags: javascript, openid-connect

I have two web application (app A and app B ), and want to use one of them (A) as iframe in another (B). I have a token in current web application (B) that it is valid in iframe (A) too. iframe web app (A) use OIDC js authentication and angularjs, now how can i send token from B to A and use that?

in my A application i have this:

```
var config = {
    authority: '...my auth server ...',
    client_id: '...'
    ...
}

mgr = new OidcTokenManager(config);

if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash.indexOf('id_token') > -1) {
    mgr.processTokenCallbackAsync().then(function () {
        //checkSessionState();
    }, function (error) {
    });
}
```

this works fine but when i use A as iframe, `mgr` not initiate correct and some properties like as `access_token` not defined!

Comment: If B has the token, you can send it to the iframe either via query param (set the iframe URL to includes also the token) or with `postMessage`.

Comment: Thanks @MoshFeu. yes i tried this but i have got that mentioned error!. `mgr` is not initiate.

Answer (score 6):

Use Javascript function for posting data from A => B => A

From Parrent application javascript code

```
 document
      .querySelector(`iframe`)
      .contentWindow.postMessage({ token: '112121' }, "*");
```

A receiver or iframe application code

```
window.addEventListener('message', receiveToken,*);

const receiveToken = message => {
    if (message.data && message.data.token){
        console.log(message.data.token)
   }
```

Comment: what do you think of this? 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/92524/is-it-safe-to-store-bearer-tokens-in-an-iframe-and-or-pass-them-back-to-the-pare/136481#136481?newreg=5dd5753f6ae04faa989b610d0f03fc5b